# SQL Delete subquery, removed duplicates records

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to write a query to removed duplicates records from the following table (valid_columns) and keep only the records with the lowest possible [order] number.

For example in the following table I would like to remove duplicate rows, region 2,3 and job 3 and keep the records with the lowest possible [order].

E.g. The input table, valid_columns looks like this:

```
name    col_order
-------------
job     1   
job     3   
status  2   
cust    2   
county  1   
state   1   
region  1
region  2
region  3
so      4
```

Desired Output:

```
name    col_order
-------------
job     1       
status  2   
cust    2   
county  1   
state   1   
region  1
so      4
```

I am trying to fix a bug and I can't figure out the SQL. Currently it uses a delete statment and a subquery. The query used at the moment looks like this:

-- 3) Remove duplicated columns

```
DELETE 
FROM valid_columns
WHERE   NOT ( col_order = ( SELECT  TOP 1 col_order 
            FROM    valid_columns   firstValid
            WHERE   name = firstValid.name
            AND col_order = firstValid.col_order
            ORDER BY col_order ASC ))
```

However, this only returns the following, which is incorrect:

```
name    col_order
-------------
job     1
county  1
state   1
region  1
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM t1
FROM valid_columns t1
WHERE col_order > 
    (SELECT MIN(col_order) from valid_columns t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
```

**EDIT:**
can be simplified to this:

```
   DELETE FROM valid_columns 
   WHERE col_order > 
        (SELECT MIN(col_order) from valid_columns t2 WHERE valid_columns.name = t2.name)
```

The DELETE statement can have a FROM clause to delete a record based on the value of a related record in a second table. In this case the FROM is not really required (I sometimes use the FROM to alias the table name because I don't like the extra typing.)

```
DELETE FROM TableA
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB On TableA.CriteriaA = TableB.CriteriaA
```

You could also try this example (might be faster if you have to do this a lot):

```
DELETE FROM valid_columns 
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM valid_columns t1 
     WHERE t1.name = valid_columns.name AND valid_columns.col_order > t1.col_order);
```

Comment: I am a bit confused when using correlated sub-queries in the where clause, can you briefly expand on your answer. It looks like it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Test table
declare @T table(Name varchar(10), col_order int)

-- Sample data
insert into @T
select 'job',     1 union all
select 'job',     3 union all
select 'status',  2 union all
select 'cust',    2 union all
select 'county',  1 union all
select 'state',   1 union all
select 'region',  1 union all
select 'region',  2 union all
select 'region',  3 union all
select 'so',      4

-- Delete using CTE and row_number()
;with cte as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by Name order by col_order) as rn
  from @T
)
delete from cte
where rn > 1

-- Result
select *
from @T
```

Or with a sub query instead of CTE

```
delete vc
from (select row_number() over(partition by Name order by col_order) as rn
      from valid_columns) as vc
where vc.rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you could replace the delete with a select to make sure you get the right results before you delete).

```
DELETE FROM [valid_columns] t1
WHERE col_order > (SELECT MIN(col_order) from [valid_columns] t2 
        WHERE t1.name = t2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
DELETE FROM valid_columns a
WHERE (SELECT MAX(col_order)
    FROM valid_columns b
    WHERE a.name = b.name) > a.col_order;
```

I recommend you make a backup of the data before testing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Delete record with binary checksum (this is working in any sql server version)

```
CREATE TABLE #t1(ID INT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1,'aa')
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (2,'bb')
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1,'aa')
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (1,'aa')
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (3,'cc')
INSERT INTO #t1(ID, VALUE) VALUES (3,'cc')
GO

-- BINARY_CHECKSUM():  are columns that we want to compare duplicates for
-- if you want to compare the full row then change BINARY_CHECKSUM() -> BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)

-- for SQL Server 2000+ a loop
-- save checksums and rowcounts for duplicates

SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(ID, VALUE) AS ChkSum, COUNT(*) AS Cnt 
INTO #t2 
FROM #t1 
GROUP BY BINARY_CHECKSUM(ID, VALUE) HAVING COUNT(*)>1

DECLARE @ChkSum BIGINT, @rc INT

-- get the first checksum and set the rowcount to the count - 1 
-- because we want to leave one duplicate

SELECT TOP 1 @ChkSum = ChkSum, @rc = Cnt-1 FROM #t2

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #t2)
BEGIN    
    -- rowcount is one less than the duplicate rows count
    SET ROWCOUNT @rc
    DELETE FROM #t1 WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(ID, VALUE) = @ChkSum 
    -- remove the processed duplicate from the checksum table
    DELETE #t2 WHERE ChkSum = @ChkSum 
    -- select the next duplicate rows to delete
    SELECT TOP 1 @ChkSum = ChkSum, @rc = Cnt-1 FROM #t2    
END 
SET ROWCOUNT 0
GO

SELECT * FROM #t1 

-- for SQL Server 2005+ a cool CTE
;WITH Numbered 
AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ChkSum ORDER BY ChkSum) AS RN, *
    FROM (
             SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(ID, VALUE) AS ChkSum
             FROM #t1
         ) t
) 
DELETE FROM Numbered WHERE RN > 1;
GO

SELECT * FROM #t1 

DROP TABLE #t1;
DROP TABLE #t2;
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could iterate through the table using a cursor and insert the first value encountered for an item in a temp table (make sure that the temp table has an unique constraint specified for the name column).

*Edit*: I've included a code snippet for convenience...

```
declare @Ti table(name varchar(10), col_order int);
declare @Tf table(name varchar(10) unique not null, col_order int not null);

declare @name varchar(10);
declare @col_order int;

-- Sample data
insert into @Ti
select 'job',     1 union all
select 'job',     3 union all
select 'status',  2 union all
select 'cust',    2 union all
select 'county',  1 union all
select 'state',   1 union all
select 'region',  1 union all
select 'region',  2 union all
select 'region',  3 union all
select 'so',      4

select * from @Ti

declare i cursor for
    select * from @Ti;

open i;
fetch next from i into @name, @col_order;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if not exists( select * from @Tf where name = @name )
    begin
        insert into @Tf(name, col_order)
            select @name, @col_order;
    end

    fetch next from i into @name, @col_order;
end

close i;
deallocate i;

select * from @Tf;
```